# Should you instantiate a model in the controller or model? - Yii, PHP

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to think of the best place to instantiate a model for a datatable that records the results of a transaction. The datatable only peripherally interacts with the view (the view dictates which "account" is selected that will pay for a transaction). However, beyond this data, all of the other data is found in the business end in the model. I know that in Yii the only time in generated code that you instantiate the model is in actionCreate in the controller - but if you want to add a new column to your database, couldn't you just as easily do it in your model?

Here is processpayment in the model Recipient.php - this makes the call to the server and gets back the result. It then saves the result into the database

```
   /** 
    * 
    * MakePayment: this function helps us pay the recipients defined by a certain paylist 
    * @param $account_id identifies the mobile-money account that will pay the recipients 
    * @param $list_id is the id of the paylist that is going to be paid. 
    * @return if 
    */
    function MakePayment($account_id, $list_id)
    {
        // instantiates new column in BulkPayment table 
        $BPModel = new BulkPayment;
        // inserts the new BPModel into the database 
        $BPModel->save();

        // instantiate the account that is being used to pay money
        $account = Account::model()->findByPk($account_id);

        // finds all individuals of the selected list
        $recipients = Recipient::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"list_id = $list_id"));

        // loop through the array of recipients, paying each of the individuals 
        foreach($recipients as $recipient)
        {
            // instantiates a new IndividualPayment
            $IPModel = new IndividualPayment;

            // Makes the transfer and returns the status of the transfer 
            $result = Recipient::model()->TransferMoney($account->msisdn, $account->pin, $recipient->msisdn, $recipient->balance);

            // defines the attributes that will be put into the 
            $attributes = array("name"=>$recipient->name, "recipient_id"=>$recipient->id, 
                            "transfer_id"=>$BPModel->id, "amount"=>$recipient->balance, "status"=>$result);
            // set the attributes of the Individual Payment 
            $IPModel->setAttributes($attributes, $safeOnly = false); 
            // save the new transaction into the database
            $IPModel->save();
        }
        // return "success";

    }
```

My question is whether it is appropriate to instantiate these two models inside of my model Recipient.php. It all seems to be working fine, and It is keeping my controller relatively lean - but I want to make sure that this is an appropriate way to instantiate a model.

Comment: "A model" doesn't exist. Your model *layer* consist of various components, including business objects and services. A controller calls service methods, and those services do any complex instantiation.

Comment: I'd say create your models where you need them. Need another model inside your other model method? Create it there. It's more straight forward than create everything in the controller and pass it along. It would also blow your controller up.

Comment: Okay, just changed with what I implemented. Give it a look to see if you think that is appropriate

Comment: What's the `$BPModel` for? You create it and save it right after but it's empty? And another thing, if money transfers are involved, you might want to have a look into [transcations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#using-transactions) to avoid trouble.